# How do I define the frequency of my mongo backup

Tags: backup, mongodb, configuration, mongodb-3.0

I want to know if there is a way to define in Mongo the frequency of backups have to be executed. There is any config file for that? An example will be excellent!!

### UPDATE

I want to create a automated mongo configuration. With this configuration I want to define the process of backup. I want the backups process be executed based on my time frequency, for example every two minutes.

So I don't know if there is a possible configuration for that. I prefer a configuration file because I want to create an automated provisioning and with commands it becomes more hard to automate.

Comment: Please explain exactly what you want to achieve, stay within MongoDBs terminology and provide as much information as you can about the desired behavior and the current behavior. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful.

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB doesn't have an automatic backup feature built-in -- you have to choose an [appropriate backup strategy](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/backups/) using command-line or third party tools.

The backup procedure will vary depending on your deployment type (standalone, replica set, sharded cluster), disk/dbpath configuration, and backup requirements.

Unless you are using a third party tool, it's best to follow a supported procedure from the MongoDB manual.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Ops Manager](https://www.mongodb.com/products/ops-manager) (can be deployed as local MMS) fits your requirement:

> …
>
> Ops Manager assists with:
>
> - Deployment. Any topology, at any scale
> - Management. Deploy new clusters. Manage, monitor, and back up existing ones
> - Upgrades. In minutes, with no downtime
> - Scaling. Add capacity, without taking the application offline
> - ***Point-in-time, Scheduled Backups***. Restore to any point in time, because disasters aren't predictable
> - Performance Alerts. Monitor 100+ system metrics and get custom alerts before the system degrades
>
> …

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. Could you please flag it for moderator attention so that they can change it to a comment? You'll be able to comment when you get a reputation of 50.

Comment: The link for Ops manager is correct and Robert would find a good tool to backup mongodb as he wish . Thanks for your update on the answer :D

Comment: @Carl please see my edit: I think Paul was trying to prompt you to add in extra details to further improve the answer after he added the link.

Comment: Note that MongoDB Ops Manager is part of a commercial Enterprise subscription. There's also a hosted version called [MongoDB Cloud Manager](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/), which also has an associated cost for backups.